# How to evaluate the performance of recommender systems without having labeled data

Tags: model-evaluation, unsupervised-learning, recommender-system, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a huge citation graph of research papers and datasets. So, there is an edge among two items when one of them cites another. So far I've used Node2Vec for creating a dataset recommender system based on the graph but I don't have a clear idea on how to evaluate this system. The system takes as an input a dataset or a paper and gives as an output the top ten most similar datasets.

I was thinking since I have also the content of these artifacts, I can exploit it for evaluation. For example, creating clusters using topic modeling and assume items in a same cluster are similar. In this way, I will have labels for the items however, I am not sure how sound this idea is...

Any comment, help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for an ML /statistical evaluation or a business / user metric? If the latter, then can you describe the business use case of the recommender , ie what's the goal for users of this system?

Comment: I'm looking for an ML/statistical evaluation. Actually the goal is to develop different models and evaluate which one is able to recommend "better", i.e, recommend items that are more similar to the input.